# jQuery Data Tables with Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery

I implemented jQuery Data Tables to display child records based on a filter in a another component. Whenever the filter is selected, the jQuery Data Table updates to only show the records related to that filtered value, however, when I start typing in the Search Field in the data table (with a filter on), the table "starts from scratch" and shows all my records - is there a way to make it work so the search "continues" based on the filter? Please see images attached below.

https://prnt.sc/j4qpm6

https://prnt.sc/j4qrav

Comment: Are you searching on lookup field, on that case it would search based on its Id value instead of text.

Comment: You could implement this logic really quickly using nothing more than lightning:datatable. jQuery is rarely worth loading in Lightning just to do basic DOM manipulation. If you're not porting an already-existing app, consider just using the readily-available components.

Comment: Use lighting datatable as told by sfdcfox or you need to do ajax call to get data and build the table dynamically a hudge task

Comment: Does lightning:datatable have a search functionality like jQuerys?

Comment: @erikvm No, but it's [trivial to implement](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/75ddb362065d6da2e9801b7f8fb78a68) in [several ways](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/754e62a39a5f0f3ddde8fda290eb33d2).

Comment: How can I get the freakin button to do something in my datatable? There is no onclick handler for the buttons in lightning:datatable?